# Spring.remoting.submitForm and SWF's on-entry

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-webflow, spring-js

I work on a project using Spring Webflow and Spring JS.

I read that `on-render` is used in SWF to execute methods every time the page is displayed and `on-entry` only when it's displayed for the first time.

So I declared in a view-state, an expression to evaluate when the web page is displayed for the first time and a transition :

```
<view-state id="whatever" model="myModel" view="myView">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="controller.methodToCallOnEntry()" />
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="myTransition" to="whatever">
        <evaluate expression="controller.methodToCallAjax()"/>
        <render fragments="myFragment" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

In the webpage, there is a javascript function which send an Ajax request to load some data. It is declared as following :

```
var params={};
params["fragments"] ="myFragment";
params["_eventId"] = "myTransition";
Spring.remoting.submitForm("","formid", params);
```

My problem is the method `methodToCallOnEntry()` is executed when the fragment `myFragment` is rendered, after every Ajax request. I want it to be executed only when the page is displayed for the first time, at the entrance of my view-state. Do you have any piece of information about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem come from your transition tag.
Because of the "To" attribute spring reload the viewstate.
So removing the "To" should solve your problem.